# onStop Error, app shuts down

Tags: java, android

I am trying to stop a melody from playing when user hit the back-button. This code is working when the file is playing, if not there will be an error and the app shuts down. How come it isnt working?

```
MediaPlayer melodisnutt;
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if ( melodisnutt.isPlaying () ) {
        melodisnutt.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Null exception or other? can you copy it here?

Comment: It might be considered helpfull to post the error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the error is happening in the onStop() method, it looks like a nullPointerException.

Try to replace :

```
if(melodisnutt.isPlaying()){
```

by

```
if(melodisnutt != null && melodisnutt.isPlaying()){
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to check if your MediaPlayer is not null,

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (melodisnutt.isPlaying () && melodisnutt != null) {
        melodisnutt.stop();
    }
}
```